Get first possible number that is not used in a range
I have two tables defined:
TABNUMBERRANGES which defines a from-to definition of numbers which determine if a new organisation can be created that belongs to that number range ( its ID is within a given from-to record for that ngesnr), example
nFrom | nto | ngesnr
------+-----+-----
  1   |  2  |   1
  3   |  4  |   2
  5   |  7  |   1

TABGESDEF which is a definition of organisations and what ges they belong to
ID | ngesnr
---+-------
 1 |   1
 2 |   1
 3 |   2
 4 |   2
 5 |   1
 7 |   1

Now what I want to achieve is to get the smallest possible number available to use for TABGESDEF so that it aligns with the allowed ranges of TABNUMBERRANGES or to say that no space is available and a new range has to be created in TABNUMBERRANGES, when creating a TABGESDEF record I know what gesdef I will assign it to, now what I need help with is going through TABNUMBERRANGES for that ngesnr to get a available number, is there any way I can do this using a SQL query.
In the given example I want to create a new TABGESDEF for ngesnr 1 and I should get 6 as my ID as its the next possible number due to the record 5-7 in TABNUMBERRANGES, if all number ranges are occupied I would simply return 0 and handle it on the front end by displaying to the user that a new number range has to be created to expand records.
I'm trying to see if there is a way to so this directly on the database and then just forward the query result to the front to avoid creating lists and looping on the frontend solution
The query should for my solution go through 1,2,5,6,7 as they are allowed for gesnr 1 and tell me if any of those numbers are not used in IDs for TABGESDEF, after checking 5 it should say 6 is the next available one.
My solution on the frontend would be to select all number range records into a list of models from query results and add select min and max
List<int> usedNumbers = new List<int> (1,2,5)
RangeModel model1 = new RangeModel() {
    Min = 1,
    Max = 2
}

RangeModel model2 = new RangeModel() {
    Min = 5,
}
Max = 7

ListModels.add(model1)
ListModels.add(Model2)
Int freeNr = 0;

Foreach ( model in ListModels) {
  For(int i = model.min;i <= model.max ;i++) {
  If(usedNumbers.contains(i) {
    FreeNr = 0;
  }
  Else {
    FreeNr = i;
  {
Return FreeNr;

But I'm wondering if I could achieve this better directly in database.
Note that for simplicity tabgesdef is ordered, this does not have to be the case as a user can define the id themselves, the solution should only take the next id automatically if defined so, the ids do not have to be in order from smallest to largest

You forgot to post your attempt to solve this problem.

@ScottHunter Unfortunately there is no attempt to post as I am not sure how i would even achieve this and am looking for pointers, but I understand where your comment is coming from

I have opted to resolve this on the server side rather than on DB so here's how i achieved this for anyone wondering
public int GetNextFreeIDforGesInRange(string nGesNr)
{
    int nReturnNr = 0;
    List<int> tabGesDefEntries = new List<int>();
    List<GesellschaftRangeModel> gesRanges = new List<GesellschaftRangeModel>();
    const string QUERY = "select nGesNr from TABGesDef order by nGesNr";
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(QUERY, PoolObj))
    {

        using (OracleDatareader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                tabGesDefEntries.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader["nGesNr"]));
            }
        }
    }

    const string QUERY2 = "select nNrVon,nNrBis,nGesNr from TABNrKreise where szTabName = 'M2TABGesDef' and nGesNr =:iNgesNr";
    using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(QUERY2, PoolObj))
    {
        cmd.BindByName = true;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("iNgesNr", nGesNr);
        using (OracleDatareader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                GesellschaftRangeModel gesellschaftRange = new GesellschaftRangeModel();
                gesellschaftRange.nGesNr = Convert.ToInt32(reader["nGesNr"]);
                gesellschaftRange.nNrVon = Convert.ToInt32(reader["nNrVon"]);
                gesellschaftRange.nNrBis = Convert.ToInt32(reader["nNrBis"]);
                gesRanges.Add(gesellschaftRange);
            }
        }
    }
    foreach (var gesrange in gesRanges)
    {
        for(int i = gesrange.nNrVon; i <= gesrange.nNrBis; i++)
        {
            if(tabGesDefEntries.Contains(i))
            {
                nReturnNr = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                nReturnNr = i;
                return nReturnNr;
            }
        }
    }
    return nReturnNr;
}

this way i either return a free number i hit or i send 0 to display error message to inform user to create a new number range.

You may generate all the possibles with recursive query, keep the ones not yet used, and then group by ngesnr  to get the min:
with tabnumberranges(nFrom, nto, ngesnr) as (
    select 1, 2, 1 union all
    select 3, 4, 2 union all
    select 5, 7, 1
),
tabgesdef(id, ngesnr) as (
    select 1, 1 union all
    select 2, 1 union all
    select 3, 2 union all
    select 4, 2 union all
    select 5, 1
)
,theoavailables(rn, ngesnr, possible) as (
    select rn, ngesnr, nfrom+level-1 as possible
    from (select rownum as rn, nFrom, nto, ngesnr from tabnumberranges)
    connect by nfrom+level-1 <= nto and prior ngesnr = ngesnr 
        and prior rn = rn and prior sys_guid() is not null
)
, availables as (
    select * from theoavailables a
    where not exists(
        select 1 from tabgesdef t 
        where t.ngesnr = a.ngesnr and t.id = a.possible
    )
)
select ngesnr, min(possible) as possible 
from availables 
group by ngesnr
;


Another way to generate the range of values is with an XML query:
select tnr.ngesnr, x.n
from tabnumberranges tnr
cross apply xmltable(
  'xs:integer($from) to xs:integer($to)'
  passing tnr.nfrom as "from", tnr.nto as "to"
  columns n number path '.'
) x;




NGESNR
N




1
1


1
2


2
3


2
4


1
5


1
6


1
7



You can then check which already exist, and get the lowest that doesn't for each ngesnr:
select tnr.ngesnr,
  coalesce(min(
    case when exists (select null from tabgesdef tgd where tgd.id = x.n) then null else x.n end
  ), 0) as id
from tabnumberranges tnr
cross apply xmltable(
  'xs:integer($from) to xs:integer($to)'
  passing tnr.nfrom as "from", tnr.nto as "to"
  columns n number path '.'
) x
group by tnr.ngesnr
order by tnr.ngesnr;




NGESNR
ID




1
6


2
0



Or to check a single ngesnr, which I think is what you want to do:
select coalesce(min(x.n), 0) as id
from tabnumberranges tnr
cross apply xmltable(
  'xs:integer($from) to xs:integer($to)'
  passing tnr.nfrom as "from", tnr.nto as "to"
  columns n number path '.'
) x
where not exists (
  select null
  from tabgesdef tgd
  where tgd.id = x.n
)
and tnr.ngesnr = 1;




ID




6



select coalesce(min(x.n), 0) as id
from tabnumberranges tnr
cross apply xmltable(
  'xs:integer($from) to xs:integer($to)'
  passing tnr.nfrom as "from", tnr.nto as "to"
  columns n number path '.'
) x
where not exists (
  select null
  from tabgesdef tgd
  where tgd.id = x.n
)
and tnr.ngesnr = 2;




ID




0



fiddle

You can use:
SELECT ngesnr,
       id
FROM   (
  SELECT r.ngesnr,
         COALESCE(n.id, 0) AS id,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY r.ngesnr ORDER BY n.id NULLS LAST) AS rn
  FROM   TABNUMBERRANGES r
         LEFT OUTER JOIN LATERAL (
           SELECT n.id
           FROM   (
                    SELECT r.nfrom + LEVEL - 1 AS id
                    FROM   DUAL
                    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= r.nto - r.nfrom + 1
                  ) n
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN TABGESDEF g
                  ON     r.ngesnr = g.ngesnr
                     AND n.id = g.id
           WHERE  g.id IS NULL
           ORDER BY n.id
           FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
         ) n
         ON 1 = 1
)
WHERE  rn = 1;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE TABNUMBERRANGES (nFrom, nto, ngesnr) AS
SELECT 1, 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 4, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 7, 1 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE TABGESDEF (ID, ngesnr) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 1 FROM DUAL;

Outputs:



NGESNR
ID




1
6


2
0



fiddle
